# Should I create a new Controller for master/detail operations in ASP:NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In an MVC5 project, there are several master/detail entities as Group / Student shown below:

```cs
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Navigation Properties
    public virtual ICollection<GroupStudent> GroupStudents { get; set; }
}

public class GroupStudent
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //Foreign key for Group
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    //Foreign key for Student
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    //Navigation Properties 
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Navigation Properties
    public virtual ICollection<GroupStudent> GroupStudents { get; set; }
}
```

I created a new Controller for both: Group and Student and defined List, Create, Details and Edit methods ind View in the related Controllers. On the other hand, I need to make master / detail operations i.e. assigning the Students to the Groups. At this step I am not sure about a good approach regarding to this issue due to the following situations below:

Should I create a new Controller (i.e. GroupStudentController) in order to these master / detail operations? Or should I create the necessary methods in StudentController or GroupController? What is the true convention regarding to such a kind of master/detail operations?

Comment: @binay just create methods and make sure your methods should reside on the controller with the most weight based on the purpose,

Comment: Honestly this is entirely a matter of preference - normally though you should keep your routing and controllers fairly in line with each other for consistency's sake (e.g. if the route is /group/xyz/addstudent then put it on the group controller).

Comment: @Sherlock Do you mean that there is no need to create an extra Controller and I should create my methods on Student or Group Controller (to which one is most related)? Could you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: @binary that's correct, no need to create a new controller

Comment: @Sherlock Thanks for your answer. Are the entity definitions i.e. Navigation and other properties (I use EF Code First) correct?

Comment: @AntP Could you please explain your suggestions a little bit more? What if I do not keep in mind the Routing issue? What do you suggest?

Comment: @binary sorry, not sure what you mean.

Comment: Also, as a general piece of advice - don't use the same objects for your views as you do for your database. Create view models specifically for your views and map to them in your controller.

Comment: @AntP I mean that could you explain a little bit more what if I create a new Controller? On the other hand, I use ViewModel always, but these are Entity models and I think the definitions of Entity Models are true. Is not it?

Comment: As entity models they look fine - just as long as you're not using them in your views. As I said, whether or not you create another controller is up to you, but I would group your controllers in the same way your group your URLs, i.e. if it's `/group/___/students/add` then put it on the group controller, if it's `/student/___/group/` then put it on the student controller. Honestly though it doesn't matter much and you can always change it.

Comment: @AntP Many thanks for your good explanations.

Comment: @Regarding to ViewModels, I sometimes use Entity Models for some operations i.e. Edit in order to not needing a mapping from ViewModel to Entity Model in the Controller. Is this correct? Or what should I do if I use ViewModel? Should I pass them to the 3rd layer of the project as ViewModel?

Comment: I would always map them for a number of reasons: - if you change your views, you don't want to have to change your entities, - there may be sensitive information on your entities that you don't want to expose (anything on your model can be changed with the right HTTP request) - it enforces a cleaner separation between your views and your data storage, so you can change one without having to change the other

Comment: @AntP I have never think of that, reallu very good approach. However, when using the Entity class, I do not have to map it and pass it to teh Data layer. Whereas, when using a ViewModel, I need to map it to Entity model in the Controller. At this point, what do you suggest? Shall I pass ViewModel from View to Controller and then map it to Entity model before passing it to the data Layer? It is the most important point for this issue.

Comment: Yes - map it to your data entity and then pass it. Even better would be to have something in the middle that decouples the two: `Controller -[ViewModel]-> ControllerToDalAdapter -[Entity]-> DAL` - that way the controller and DAL are totally independent and the adapter's job is to bring them together. This is often the natural conclusion if you use TDD starting at the controller level.

Comment: Many many thanks for clarification. I think it is enough for me to map from ViewModel to Entity Model on the related Controller method as I pass the model from Controller to Data Layer directly. **I think there is no problem with this approach?** Now it is time for me to switch to use ViewModel on the Views :) Regards...

Comment: @binary yes mapping in the controller is perfectly reasonable - the key is to shield the entity models from your views (and action parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to create an extra controller, just create a method in any of the existing controllers and choose the controller according to the business need of the required method.

Ex: If you have a method that should assign a student to a group and this action will be done from the students list page, then make it in the Students controller, if you have a page that will popup from the groups list to manage the students for the selected group, then make it in the groups controller.

Make your business drive.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I have an issue at this stage: **1)** I sometimes pass Entiy Model from View to Controller and then pass it to the Data layer directly. **2)** On the other hand, sometimes I pass ViewModel from View to Controller and then **map** it to Entiy Model in the Controller before passing it to the Data Layer. So, is the 2nd way is the best approach? If so, I user Automapper for mapping. Is there a better way for passing the ViewModel to the Data Layer? What is the best convention regarding to this issue?

Comment: You sould always pass what the view only needs, no extra data, if your entity model is needed in the view, for ex: you have a table named Student and you are displaying all the information in the view in order to edit it, then it is fine to go with the entity model directly and not the view model.
When you pass the view model to the controller, you should pass it a business layer first to do any business validation then it should be passed to the data access layer for persistence, before you pas from controller to business, you should map it if you are using data transfer object

Comment: Thanks for reply. But according to AntP says, it seems to be not good idea to use Entity Model on the View so that someone can manipulate data operations using it. So, in that case it seems to be better to use ViewModel always in the Views and map it to the related Entity model on the Controller before sending it to Data Layer. What do you think about that?

Comment: If your view will need all the properties inside your entity model, then you can pass your entity model directly instead of cloning the same class, but in case there are additional properties that you won't need in the view then get your own view model, as for the manipulation, you will always do validation in your controller action to avoid it.